# How to change the background color of row in a listview after the list gets populated

Tags: android, listview, position

I have created a `custom adapter` and added it on the listview.
After that I have created the **AutoCompleteTextView** and the **Button** nemed as `Search Button.`
So I did stuff for the searching from the list and by clicking on the search button,I scroll the list to the searched text by using this line.

```
listViewOS.setSelection(position);
```

My question is

**I want to change the color of the row found by the search procedure.** I have the position and I am passing the position to the getView and trying to change the color of row using this code.

```
if(position == posn)
{
    Log.i("Log","Inside if");
    rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
}
return rowView;
```

It is printing the log when the position matched,but its not changing the background color of the row.

*I think it is happening because, I am trying to change the color of the row of listview which is already populated.
So how can I change the color of the row of listview which is already populated.
I want to do this because I want to show the the searched row in the highlighted color.*

I have the position, but not able to do this.

please help

Comment: I am using the BaseAdapter

Comment: Try  row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Comment: I have tried this also. its not solved

Comment: @nick See the solution posted by me. It is working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
listview.setSelection(position);
View rowView = listview.getChildAt(position);
rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
```

It works for me.

Thanks.

Comment: getting nullpointer exception at rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);

Comment: I am calling this on one button click and it working well. I you are calling this before list with adapter is not being populated. Try to handle that and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after

Comment: not solved. the background color of the row not changing. And it arises 1more issue. ie. listViewOS.setSelection(position); is also get refreshed. So the selection also lost by this.

Comment: what does your row actually look like? it could be going through with the code, changing the *background* color, but if something is blocking this background, you won't see it. as for the other issue, simply call `notifyDataSetChanged()` *before* your `setSelection` command.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have use custom adapter extends ArrayAdapter and Implement like this. May be this will help you

Have used this example [ListView](http://www.androidchennai.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-listview-example.html)

Comment: please see the question mate. I have already tried this and its not getting solved

Comment: @nick Problem is with adapter only. I have also came across this scenario with more example. At last i found the custom adapter

Comment: I dont think that the problem is with the adapter, LET ME EXPLAIN: I am creating the list and populating it with the custom adapter,its all working very fine, here the adapter scenario solved. the problem is what, I want to change the background of the row which is already been populated. this is about my question